# Play Swagger UI url alias

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, swagger-ui

I have `Swagger UI` for API documentation, I use the same approach like in [official specification](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger) for accessing it I use next URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/assets/swagger.json
```

But I want to use `http://localhost:9000/docs/` instead. I won't want to use `WS` for delegating, I would like to use single line in `routes`, like this:

```
GET /docs controllers.Assets.at(path:String="/public/lib/swagger-ui", file:String="index.html?url=/assets/swagger.json")
```

Or

```
GET /docs controllers.Assets.at(path:String="/public/lib/swagger-ui", file:String="index.html")
```

and `http://localhost:9000/docs?url=/assets/swagger.json`

What shold I change so it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make shortness in route file for the URL `/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/assets/swagger.json` because `index.html` is generated by `swagger-ui plugin` to `public` directory and requires access to files nearby (like js and css files). `Play swagger-ui` uses `javascript` for fetching `json` based description of your routes via URL parameter for further parsing this document to swagger-ui, in your case it's `/assets/swagger.json` endpoint.

I tried to make the mapping swagger's `index.html` file, so pass `json` location like `URL parameter` directly:

```
GET     /swagger-ui         controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/lib/swagger-ui", file = "index.html")
```

Play couldn't render this page, and CSS wasn't found. I appended dummy mapping to every file in swagger's default directory `/public/lib/swagger-ui`:

```
GET     /*file              controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/lib/swagger-ui", file)
```

Even after that Play couldn't properly render `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

How it can be solved without Play-Swagger:

1. Create directory **public\swagger** in your project;
2. Download all files from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist and copy them to **public\swagger**;
3. Copy your swagger.json (it's specification, right?) to **public\specification**;
4. Add to your **routes** file next line:

> GET     /docs
>   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public/specification", file: Asset
>   = "swagger.json")

Comment: my `swagger.json` is obtained from the endpoint /assets/swagger.json

Comment: And I want to solve it with play-swagger, I don't need native swagger-api

Comment: @pacman, got it, but what's the benefit of solving it using play-swagger, not native swagger-api?

Comment: Benefit is ability to generate documentation from domain objects on the fly.